# How to remember page setup settings and margins in Access 2003 mde file?

Tags: ms-access, printing, margins, page-setup

I have a small bookkeeping application which is supposed to run on a client's computer and uses a printer which prints on a narrow paper roll.
I don't want to share my mdb so I make an mde file. I setup the mdb file at my computer to settings I want and it remembers just fine. When I make an mde file the settings are still there, the smaller margins, printer information etc. However, when I send the file to my client, page setup is reverted to A4 format (the paper roll printer is the default at my client's computer) and the margins are changed (left, top and bottom stay the same but the right margin is changed) so the program prints several blank sides on print preview and uses a lot of paper roll when actually printing.

The client can setup margins and printer manually but the problem is, she has to do this every time she wants to print something, which is pretty tedious.

She runs the database on Runtime Access 2013.
I have tried creating my mde in Access 2010, and I have tried installing Office 2003 on her computer and running my mde but it doesn't work.

However, it works fine if I copy mdb to her computer or if I create mde file on the spot.
What I need is to be able to create mde files at my computer which will work fine wherever deployed.

Is there a chance for an mde file to remember page setup settings for each report and if not, how can I programatically change report margins and printer to a specific configuration?
Also, is there a chance to store printer name and margin values in a table and use those values when printing as this will enable my client to change her printer without the need to change vba code as it is impossible in mde?

Comment: May be of interest: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.databases.ms-access/ZEJuGiqke2E

Comment: Thanks. This didn't offer a solution but it helped me find it. To anyone who tries this and it doesn't work, instead of using Application.Printer.Leftmargin=... they should try Me.Printer.LeftMargin etc. It worked for me.